# IEnumerable<SelectListItem> comes back as NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an MVC app I'm using as a proof of concept, but I'm having a problem implementing one part of our design into it.

I have TaxRate.cs:

```cs
[Key]
public short TaxId { get; set; }
public short LocationId { get; set; }
[Column("TaxRate", TypeName = "decimal(12, 5)")]
[Display(Name = "Rate")]
public decimal TaxRate1 { get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(21)]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string Description { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(12, 2)")]
[Display(Name = "Taxed Amount Minimum")]
public decimal AmountMin { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(12, 2)")]
[Display(Name = "Tax Amount Maximum")]
public decimal AmountLimit { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
```

TaxGroup.cs:

```cs
[Key]
public short TaxGroupId { get; set; }
public short LocationId { get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(21)]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(100)]
public string Description { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
```

TaxGroupViewModel.cs:

```cs
public short TaxGroupId { get; set; }
public short LocationId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TaxRates { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AppliedRates { get; set; }
```

This view is used to add rates from TaxRates to AppliedRates.

AddRates.cshtml:

```cs
@model TaxGroupViewModel

@{
    var loc = ViewData["LocationId"];
}

<main>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddRates", "Location", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <h1>Add taxes to @Model.Name</h1>

        <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="LocationId" value="@Model.LocationId" />
        <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="TaxGroupId" value="@Model.TaxGroupId" />
        <input hidden="hidden" asp-for="Name" value="@Model.Name" />

        <section class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Available Rates</h2>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.TaxRates, new SelectList(Model.TaxRates, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "col-md-6 form-control" })
                <br />
                <input type="button" id="apply" value="Add" class="col-md-2" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Applied Rates</h2>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AppliedRates, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "col-md-6 form-control" })
                <br />
                <input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove" class="col-md-2" />
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button id="savebtn" type="submit" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary" onlick="">Save</button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Edit", "Location", new { locationId = loc }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </section>
    }
</main>
<script>
    $('#apply').click(function () {
        inHTML = "";
        $("#TaxRates option:selected").each(function () {
            var optionVal = $(this).val();
            var exists = false;

            $('#AppliedRates option').each(function () {
                if (this.value == optionVal) {
                    exists = true;
                }
            });

            if (!exists) {
                inHTML += '<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>';
            }
        });

        $("#AppliedRates").append(inHTML);

        var ids = "";

        $('#AppliedRates option').each(function () {
            ids += this.value + ",";
        });

        $('#hidden1').val(ids);
    });

    $('#remove').click(function () {
        $("#AppliedRates option:selected").remove();

        var ids = "";

        $('#AppliedRates option').each(function () {


            ids += $(this).val() + ";";
        });

        $('#hidden1').val(ids);
    });
}
</script>
```

The problem I'm having is when I submit the form, TaxRates and AppliedRates come back to the controller method as NULL. Doing some research, I saw that it may be because I have to create a custom model bind for TaxRate.cs. Is this the only way to proceed or is there another way?

EDIT:

`LocationId=94&TaxGroupId=12&Name=asdfasd&TaxRates=396&TaxRates=397&TaxRates=398&TaxRates=399&__`

AddRates method:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddRates(TaxGroupViewModel vm)
        {
            var groups = new List<TaxGrouping>();

            var applied = vm.AppliedRates;

            foreach (var item in applied)
            {
                var grouping = new TaxGrouping()
                {
                    TaxGroupId = vm.TaxGroupId,
                    TaxId = short.Parse(item.Value)
                };

                groups.Add(grouping);
            }

            await _locationRepository.Add(groups);

            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Location", new { locationId = vm.LocationId });
        }
```

Comment: @mjwills added!

Comment: Okay, I replaced the image with the text.

Comment: Please share the source code for the `AddRates` action.

Comment: I encourage you to look at the [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/), [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) functions. Combining them would save you a lot of code... (see example on the map page).

Comment: @mjwills added. In this method, TaxRates and AppliedRates comes back as null while LocationId and TaxGroupId are the correct values.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I will check those out! Is this to help with passing between TaxRates and AppliedRates?

Comment: No, just an unrelated comment :).

Comment: `TaxGroupViewModel` (as taken by the POST endpoint) shouldn't have a property of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. You are passing multiple numbers, so it should be `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: Based on your posted data, it would not be bound to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` type property automatically, as @mjwills mentioned, you can try to modify the type of `TaxRates` property to `IEnumerable<int>` etc. Besides, if you do not want to modify your model class or property, you can try to implement a custom model binder to bind `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TaxRates` based on the received `TaxRates=396&TaxRates=397&TaxRates=398&TaxRates=399`.

Answer (score -2):

In your AddRates controller there is a return view command you should edit there like this

```
TaxGroupViewModel t=new TaxGroupViewModel();
Return view(t.tolist());
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile. For a number of different reasons.